# AWS OpsWorks RDS connection

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-opsworks

I'm still exploring AWS and right now OpsWorks looks like a great solution for what I'm looking for. I have never been exposed to Chef and I'm sort of lost in it right now.

I'm trying to establish a connection between my PHP App Server layer and an RDS instance. Right now, I have a `globals.php` file with all of my global settings etc including the DB connection details.

At the moment I've established a connection between my app and RDS by simply inserting the DB con values into my `globals.php` file, but all of the documentation seems to indicate that I need to use chef to make this connection, and by extension I assume I need to make this connection to make proper use of the Memecahed layer.

Can someone please shed some light on my situation? Is my method of DB connection bad practice and if so can someone give me a rundown of how I would go about implementing a chef recipe to connect to RDS.

Thanks everyone! x

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to associate your application with the RDS service layer. Once done OpsWorks built in Chef cookbooks should write the config information to a [file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-connectdb.html) (exactly what file is specific to what kind of app you're using, but you're using PHP so it's `/srv/www/app_shortname/shared/config/opsworks.php`. ([Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-connectdb.html)) I guess it creates a new PHP class and you can call that to access your variables (not 100% sure what I'm looking at in PHP land).

So, theoretically you should be able to just using that existing file that Amazon set up for you, no custom cookbook stuff involved at all.